# Not all AD users appear in TFS

Tags: tfs

We're using TFS 2013. The problem we're facing is this:
Several Active Directory users are listed in TFS under the Control panel/Security/Users, but not all.

Where can I control which AD users will also be able to access TFS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The displayed names are only the names that have been assigned to something and synched into the TFS db's by the AD sync service. If you enter in the full AD name of a valid user in any of the security assignments it will end up showing in the user select list after the next sync run (every hour if I remember correctly).

I.e. you can assign users that are not displayed in the list.